# How to open a screen without user interaction using firebase notification in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want to make an app , which is open a screen without user interaction when ,it receive notifaction from firebase and app is not in background.I send a data message  and check message.data and notification . I have done this things in android studio with java and it is easy . but in flutter , it is not easy

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message, {BuildContext? context}) async {
await Firebase.initializeApp();

```
  if(message.notification !=null){
  
    if(message.data['key1'] =='N7'){
      if(context !=null){
        Navigator.pushNamed(context,LoginScreen.screenId);
      }

    }
  }

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}



 @override
  void initState() {FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of ways to do it.

1 You can use [flutter_foreground_task](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task) by using utility

```
FlutterForegroundTask.launchApp();
```

with route

```
FlutterForegroundTask.launchApp('/next_page');
```

honestly I don't know if it's work IOS according to docs (you can).

2 or set parameter fullScreenIntent to true in AndroidNotificationDetails if your using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and then you can handle the action (it's work like someone click notification ) but is work only in android.

Comment: ,thank you for your reply. I tried this but it did not work for me. but when i click the notification it open the app. but i want to do it without click.